# Google Places API OVER_QUERY_LIMIT with fewer than 50 requests

Tags: google-places-api

I just started using the Google Maps and Google Places APIs for an app I am developing. I keep getting the `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` error when sending a request to the `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json` endpoint even though I have made an absurdly low number of requests.

I know it is not the API key because I do not get the invalid key error unless I change or remove the `key` query parameter I am sending.

My code for calling the API (from a NativeScript Angular app running on Android):

```
import { Location as Geolocation } from "nativescript-geolocation";
import { TokenModel } from "nativescript-ui-autocomplete";
// And other stuff

// Injectable class, blah blah blah

public getRestaurantSuggestions(
    search: string,
    location: Geolocation = null
): Observable<TokenModel[]> {
    let route: string = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json";
    route += `?key=${AppConstants.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_DEV_KEY}`;
    route += `&keyword=${search}`;
    route += "&types=establishment";

    if (location) {
        route += `&location=${location.latitude},${location.longitude}`;
        route += `&radius=${AppConstants.GOOGLE_MAPS_SEARCH_RADIUS}`;
    }

    return this._http.get(route).pipe(
        map((response: Response) => {
            return response.json();
        }),
        map((response: {
            error_message: string,
            predictions: { name: string }[],
            status: string
        }) => {
            if (response.error_message) {
                throw new Error(`${response.status}: ${response.error_message}`);
            }

            return response.predictions.map(p => {
                return new TokenModel(p.name, null);
            });
        }),
        catchError((error: Error) => {
            return throwError(error.message);
        })
    );
}
```

Interesting notes:

- I made a few erroneous requests last night trying to figure out how to use the API
- I suddenly got nothing but `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` error responses despite seeing fewer than 40 requests on my Google developer console
- Today (a little less than 24 hours later) I was able to send one successful request but then got `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` again

Here are the current numbers in my "In use APIs" table in the Google developer console:

```
In use APIs
Select an API to view details. Figures are for the last 30 days.

API                    |  Requests  |  Errors  |  ...
Maps SDK for Android   |  11        |  0       |  ...
Places API for Web     |  31        |  29      |  ...
```

As you can see, there are FAR fewer than the maximum number of requests that is supposed to be allowed without setting up a credit card or whatever.

What is happening?

**EDIT**

[According to this](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage-and-billing#basic-data), Google JUST changed it so that you must set up billing in order to use the Places API. As much as it begrudges me to do so when I am just getting acquainted with the API while developing an alpha of my app, I will go ahead and set up billing information and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

It is as I suspected. As I stated in the edit to my question, [according to this](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage-and-billing#basic-data), Google JUST changed it so that you must set up billing in order to use the Places API.

It annoys me to no end that that was the case, but I suppose that's Google for you.

Now I'm on to a different adventure - getting `INVALID_REQUEST` errors on every request. :/